# How do I create a service endpoint CRM 2013

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

CRM 2013 On-Premise

Hello,

I need to display a calendar of events. The information I need all comes from our custom "event" entity.

My first thought was to use this as an excuse to do something I haven't done before and add a new service endpoint. That being said I didn't find anything in the sdk or via Google.

So stumbling around in the dark I see that in the plugin registration tool I can register a service endpoint just like I do a workflow or plugin.

So do I just create a service endpoint like any other or are there special considerations?

Thank You

Comment: Do you have an external application?  Maybe all you need to do is use the standard retrieve SDK message. Registering a plugin or workflow would necessary of you need custom logic to fire before or after an event in CRM.

Comment: The calendar is an external application. For now an aspx using the telerik scheduler control. So I was wanting my service to output a business object that I could simply bind to the control. Eventually this would move to a SP web part. If I have to build the biz obj in code behind of the aspx I can I was just hoping for a cleaner approach.

Comment: You could use Linq to CRM to get what you need - that would be the simplest in my opinion - otherwise maybe build a new action - it could return multiple parameters including an entity collection.

Comment: So are you saying to query CRM db directly with Linq cause I can project a biz object from the query or are you referring to using the LinqtoCRM project on codeplex. http://linqtocrm.codeplex.com/

Comment: Not the db directly, no. There is a standard Dynamics CRM LINQ provider: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328028.aspx. It might take a bit of time to get up to speed with Linq to CRM, but I have found it hugely useful. Other options are QueryExpression and FetchXML - it is best to stay away form the db unless it is SSRS reports on filtered views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new endpoint cannot be created - you have to work with the standard CRUD messages - those are available for every entity.

2013 introduced Actions which are basically custom messages: [Power Objects has an intro](http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2013/11/22/actions-in-dynamics-crm-2013/).

A custom workflow activity can be added to an action in the workflow designer in the same way that a custom workflow activity can be added to a workflow in the workflow designer.

Comment: OK...so in a solution there is a section for service endpoints and it infers..to me at least...that you could create a service endpoint, register it, and include it in your solution...must be legacy then?

Comment: As far as I know it was never an option to add a service endpoint, but I have only worked with 2011+. If you need to create a custom message I suggest you check out Actions.

Comment: Just FYI further reading shows that service end points are for Azure integrations which in my case is not applicable.

Comment: I must say, Microsoft does mislead you if you can only use Azure. If the service is a rest service and maintains the same Authentication and Authorization schema as set out as by ADFS, we should be allowed to register our own Restful services. Do anyone have maybe more insight into this ?

Comment: They are labeled in the UI as service endpoints but it is clear in the documentation that this is for Azure integration ONLY.

Answer (score 2):

Because actions don't work in offline mode, I use a dummy entity "ServiceJSON" with some input parameters fields and 1 output param and a plugin register on Retrieve for this entity.
I fill the output param with my json via the plugin.

To call the "service", I just try to retrieve this entity in js (with a fetchxml) with my input parameters and I read the output :)

Comment: +1 for clever approach. I'm definately going to tuck trhis one away and pretend I thought of it on my own every time I use it. :)